Is there a relationship between Alcohol and Tekhelet
Iirc Alcohol is from the Arabic word, but what is the root of the word? Is it Al-Kekhol? The All-Inclusive? Because per Tikune Zohar there are four primary colors (White, red, yarok -- light or mid spectrum colours, black.. corresponding to YKWK and the sefirot etc. as is known -- and Tekhelet "blue" is the generality of all, כל , of them as the TZ states).
Now then the Sages said, Alcohol (wine) is the best medicine. (Ref -- please insert?) and we see whatever (כל) sits and ferments anaerobically turns to alcohol. Is there some relation here between Al-kekhol and Tekhelet and is it the same consonant or not, the Kh in both words?

כֹּהַל m.n. NH alcohol. [From Arab. kuḥl , which is related to Aram.-Syr. כּוּחְלֶא , Ethiop. kwehl , and Heb. כָּחַל . Its modern sense is due to the analogy of the fitness of this powder.

Alcohol really just meant the distillation process in Arabic. It got it's name when some Jewish lady in Egypt ~1,000 years ago started distilling the khol (eye makeup/medicine) and made it more potent. It soon referred to all distillation. Afterwards, when people concentrated (sorry) the word to be used for distillation of spirits, it took it's modern exclusive meaning for that.

Both alcohol and techelet were used in the Beit HaMikdash :)

Alcohol's etymology comes from a combination of French and Arabic- French was "alcool," which translates to alcohol, and Arabic's part of the project either being Al-kuhul or more likely al-kohl, which literally translates to "the powder that is the cause and solution to all of life's problems." Kohl is a substance used in medicine, but the word was also widely used to refer to all powders, and eventually the distilled liquids that came from boiling those powders.

This is not a question about Judaism.
